# multiple sum().compute() in dask on a very large set of data

Tags: bigdata, dask, dask-distributed

I have a dask dataframe with 100 partitions (aggregating 100 json files together that are around 45GB). I want to calculate a number of metrics with .sum().compute() on around 15-20 columns. For each .compute() it takes so long. Is there a better way to do all these sum().compute() in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better way!

Simply, do `.sum()` on each thing you want - this produces lazy prescriptions of the work to be done - and then pass the set of them to `dask.compute()`, and it will do them all in one go, sharing any intermediate values where possible.

```
dask.compute(df.a.sum(), df.b.sum(), df.c.sum(), df.d.sum())
```

Alternatively, you can probably simply select the columns you want (`df[[col1, col2, ...]]`) and then do a single `.sum().compute()`

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].sum().compute()
```

Comment: Just wondering if I create a new column called x_sum and without using .compute() push back the whole dataframe to database, and do the aggregation in database query? .compute() takes a long time to run

Comment: I do not follow your flow here, sounds like a different question altogether.

Comment: I did what you suggested but .compute() takes more than 1 hour, so thinking another way to do